# State taxes as an international student on opt who worked as contractor

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, contractor, f1-student-visa

I worked in the U.S. from February 2017 to January 2018 on an F1-OPT status. I was hired as a contractor so I got my monthly salary without any deductions. I used Glacier tax services to  file my federal return but I'm still confused on what's the the easiest way to file my state return for D.C. I received 1099-MISC forms for whatever I earned. I need to pay my taxes but need to understand how much to pay and how.

I've been checking the DC state tax website and other places but I haven't found an answer because of my very specific condition.

Comment: Hey i'm also having the same problem now. Did you find any solution of paying taxes. Please let me know.